# Routing in Angular 16 not working for Standalone Components

Tags: angular, angular16

Code - https://github.com/suyashjawale/Angular16

I have generated my Angular 16 project using following command and selected routing to yes.

```
ng new myapp --standalone
```

And then I generated other components using

```
ng g c components/home
```

Since, i used `--standalone` the boilerplate files are different. (Eg. New file app.routes.ts)

[image] File Structure

Now I want to implement routing So I added the following code to app.routes.ts.

[image] app.routes.ts

[image] app.component.html

But the routing doesn't happen. Idk why?. I have restarted the app. still it doesn't work.
So i implemeted loadComponent. But still it doesn't work. Code below.

[image] loadComponent way.

Am i doing anything wrong. It works with angular 15. But it has app.routing.module.ts. I have restarted the app but still it doesn't work.

FYI - component is standalone

[image]
home.component.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interesting part is the `main.ts`. Here is a function called `bootstrapApplication`. This should look like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),

    [...]
  ]
});
```

Important, too (for Standalone Components in your case): In your `app.component.ts` you need to import `RouterLink`, too. If you wanna use `RouterLinkActive`, too import it too:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
```

APP_ROUTES are your `routes: Routes [ { path..... } ]`

Comment: Yes, its there. https://github.com/suyashjawale/Angular16

Comment: It was a missing import. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I migrated my POC Project to Angular 16 successfully. The project  is using RouterLink in many components. I had to implement it every component that requires routerLink. Is there any alternative to it?

Comment: No. That is like standalone components work. In React, as example, you need to import all at the same way.